# Displaying mp3 files from all folders and subfolders present in SD card

Tags: android

I am trying to set a ring tone for my alarm application. For this i need to display all songs with .mp3 extension present in various folders and sub folders in SD card.

I want only the .mp3 files to be displayed and not any of the folders/ sub folders. I already have a coding where songs are displayed from SD card and not from within the sub folders.  All coding given retrieve songs only from a specific folder which i dont need. I need every mp3 song that exists in sd card.

```
public class Mp3filterActivity extends Activity{
    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         ListView listsong =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.songlist);

        ArrayList<String> mp3list = new ArrayList<String>();
        mp3list=mp3select();
        Toast.makeText(this, "mp3files" +mp3list, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Mp3filterActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mp3list);
        listsong.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }

    public ArrayList<String> mp3select(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        //if (home.isDirectory())

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) 
        {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) 
            {
                   list.add(file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));        
                }
        }
        return list;
    }

    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter 
    {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") ||name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user147969 Dude you really needed to learn basics as for your question `How to add getMp3() method" I suggest you to refer through following basic tutorials.[link]http://androidsamples.blogspot.in/2009/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html

Answer (score 1):

First, don't hardcode `/sdcard/`, since the SDcard might not be mounted under that directory. Use the [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) instead. Also, check if there is an SDcard first.

---

You don't need to crawl through all those folders to get every Audio file on the device (external *and* internal). Android exposes the [`MediaStore`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) which:

> [...] contains meta data for all available media on both internal and external storage devices.

It has a [`MediaStore.Audio`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html)-subclass for all audio-specific actions.

Comment: @user1479469 nope. [RTFM](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through each folders recursively to achieve that.

A sample code looks like this:

```
getMp3s(Arraylist<File> list, File dir){
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for(File file : files){
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            getMp3s(list, file);
        }else{
            //add mp3s to list here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MediaStore` is better than scanning sdcard hence you can get,`Albums`,`Artist`,`Path` etc,try do all the best :)